# Am I using Pluralizer wrong?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, pluralize

Paging Jay Querido...

Downloaded the Pluralizer NuGet package. My goal is to display a string like so:

**X contracts with Y partners in Z countries**

If X is 1, word should change to contract. If Z is 1, word should change to country. Same for 1 partner.

The following does not work. It always results in TotalContracts being the same number for the whole sentence.

```
@Html.Pluralize("{_} {contract} with {_} {partner} in {_} {country}",
    Model.TotalContracts, Model.TotalPartners, Model.TotalCountries)
@* result is X contracts with X partners in X countries *@
```

The following does work, but is not quite as readable. Is there a better way?

```
@Html.Pluralize("{_} {contract}", Model.TotalContracts) with
@Html.Pluralize("{_} {partner}", Model.TotalPartners.Count) in
@Html.Pluralize("{_} {country}", Model.TotalCountries)
```

Comment: As soon as I post I find the answer. Seems this works: `@Html.Pluralize("{0|_} {0|contract} with {1|_} {1|partner} in {2|_} {country}", Model.TotalContracts, Model.TotalPartners, Model.TotalCountries)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like my comment obscured an underscore. This works with a single call to Pluralize:

```
@Html.Pluralize("{0|_} {0|contract} with {1|_} {1|partner} in {2|_} {country}",
    Model.TotalContracts, Model.TotalPartners, Model.TotalCountries)
```